# How can I validate users text input when using a java scanner class?

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I am a beginner at programming Java looking for some advice.
I have created a very simple program/application asking users to enter commands which in turn display basic shapes on a graphics screen at the user specified location, size and color.

I have used the scanner class to get users input from the keyboard (e.g. user types **move 100 150** and the graphics screen **pen** moves to X = 100, Y = 150 or types **circle 100** to display a circle radius 100 at the specified x,y co-ordinate)

I want to return an error message if the user inputs an incorrect command or tried to enter nothing or random keystrokes (e.g. if they misspelled a command or did not specify enough values for the command)

At the moment the program crashes and must be restarted

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Assign1 {


public final static void main(String [] args) {

    System.out.println("Let's draw something on the screen!");

    GraphicsScreen graphics = new GraphicsScreen();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // used to read the keyboard

    String next;    // stores the next line input
    String[] one;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter a command (\"stop\") to finish : ");
        System.out.print("Type 'help' for a list of commands ");
        next = input.nextLine();
        one = next.split(" ");

        String command = one[0];

        if(next.contains("help")) {
            System.out.println("Type 'move' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to move the graphical pointer.");
            System.out.println("Type 'circle' followed by a radius value to output a circle.");
            System.out.println("Type 'line' followed by an X and Y co-ordinate to draw a line.");
            System.out.println("Type 'clear' to reset the graphical canvas.");
        }


        if(next.contains("move")) {

            int x = 0;

            int y = 0;

            x = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);

            y= Integer.parseInt(one[2]);

            graphics.moveTo(x, y);

        } 



        if( command.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {


            int radius = 0;


            radius = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);


            graphics.circle(radius);

        } 


        if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {

            int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

            x = Integer.parseInt(one[1]);

            y= Integer.parseInt(one[2]);

            graphics.lineTo(x,y);

        }


        if(next.contains("clear")) {
            graphics.clear();
        }

    } while ( next.equalsIgnoreCase("stop") == false );

    System.out.println("You have decided to stop entering commands. Program terminated!");

    graphics.close();
```

I have all the necessary code for the graphics screen in another document called

```
graphicscreen.java
```

I am just looking for suggestion of how I can validate the users text input to give an error message if anything but one of my specific commands are typed.

I have tried using if statements and while loops and others I have found on various web pages but none have yet worked.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: updated code using else statements

Comment: what do you enter, when you receive ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `else if` and `else`. An `else if` condition only gets checked if all the `if` and `else if` conditions above it evaluated to `false`. An `else` block only gets run if all the `if` and `else if` conditions above it evaluated to `false`.

```
if(next.contains("move")) {
} 
else if( command.equalsIgnoreCase("circle")) {
} 
else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("line")) {
}
else if(next.contains("clear")) {
}
else {
 //input invalid
}
```

Comment: if i change all my if statements into else if statements would the last else statement become :
    else {
    system.out.println("error message");
   }

Comment: Yes, and it will only print if the input is not a command you expected.

Comment: im getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Assign1.main(Assign1.java:51)

Answer (score 0):

use `nested if-else` rather than `only if`.

```
 if(command1istrue){
  }
else if(command2istrue){

 }
else if(command3istrue){
}
else {
system.out.println("Error you have entered the wrong command");
}
```

check [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp1/node99.html)

Comment: getting this error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Assign1.main(Assign1.java:51)